# How do I make a standalone Camel application that can automatically shutdown?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a simple file transfer application that is run as a standalone Java application. It takes files from an SFTP endpoint and moves them to another endpoint.

Files are deleted from the SFTP endpoint after they are transferred. **When there are no more files left, it would be ideal to have the program end**. However, I haven't been able to find a solution where I can start Camel and get it to **end conditionally (like when there are no more files in the SFTP endpoint)**. My workaround is currently to start Camel and then have the main thread sleep for a very long time. The user then has to kill the application manually (via CTRL+C or otherwise).

Is there a better way to have the application terminate such that it does so automatically?

Below is my current code:

In CamelContext (Spring App Context):

```
<route>
    <from uri="sftp:(url)" />
    <process ref="(processor)" />
    <to uri="(endpoint)" />
</route>
```

main() method:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
  CamelContext camelContext = appContext.getBean(CamelContext.class);

  try
  {
    camelContext.start();
    Thread.sleep(1000000000); // Runs the program for a long time -- is there a better way?
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  UploadContentLogger.info("Exiting");
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could change you route something like this:

```
<route>
    <from uri="sftp:(url)?sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle=true" />
    <choose>
        <when>
            <simple>${body} != null</simple>
            <process ref="(processor)" />
            <to uri="(endpoint)" />
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <process ref="(shutdownProcessor)" />
        </otherwise>
    </choose>
</route>
```

Notice using `sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle=true`

And here is `shutdownProcessor`

```
public class ShutdownProcessor {
    public void stop(final Exchange exchange) {
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    exchange.getContext().stop();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // log error
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

Actually I didn't run this code, but it should work as desired.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to point you to this FAQ also
http://camel.apache.org/how-can-i-stop-a-route-from-a-route.html